# How can I export photo ratings, tags, etc. from Aperture for import into other software?

Tags: metadata, apple-aperture

I am about to transfer all my photos from Aperture to Bibble Pro. I would like to retain all my ratings, tags, colors that I have attached to photos and then import it into Bibble. How would I go about doing this? Should I somehow store all my data in EXIF or IPTC and then somehow import that data in Bibble? I am shooting raw and using a Mac (Aperture is Mac only).

If so, how can I do that?

Comment: do you use raw or jpeg,  mac / pc. i had problems writing some metadata, especially 'faces' data on raw files on my mac, jpegs were fine though.

Comment: just re-read the question - the first sentence mentions moving to bibble, the second sentence says you have data in bibble, maybe the question needs an edit to clarify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't write the ratings to the files in Aperture, so, instead, make keywords of the ratings (1star, 2star, 3star etc) and write those to them. Then in Bibble you can search on those keywords and apply Bibble ratings